# Angular Watchers Count for multiple ng-if with same variable

Tags: angularjs

Adding multiple time ng-if with same variable will cost more watcher?

I mean will it be a performance issue if I use as follows?

```
<span ng-if="contentLoaded">{{::MY_CONTENT_1}}</span>
<span ng-if="contentLoaded">{{::MY_CONTENT_2}}</span>
```

Or is there any good approach to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It seems that @Jon Quarfoth is right :

"Unless there's some kind of smart deduping going on under the covers that I don't know about, I'm pretty sure that each ng-if creates a watch.

A quick look at the source shows a $scope.$watch being created in the ngIf directive's link function:

http://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/…"

Comment: Unless there's some kind of smart deduping going on under the covers that I don't know about, I'm pretty sure that each ng-if creates a watch. A quick look at the source shows a $scope.$watch being created in the ngIf directive's link function: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L89

Comment: OK. That means it is also a costly one. So is there any approach can I take to render my content after loading from AJAX, but things should have one time binding. Because after loading the content it will not be changed.